# React PropTypes arrayOf oneOf shape A or shape B

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Im trying to nest `oneOf()` a list of `shape()`'s, in `arrayOf()` but Im getting an error.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `tabs[0]` of value `[object Object]` supplied to `MyComponent`, expected one of [null,null].

Is it possible to pass `oneOf()` a list of `shape()`'s?

```
tabs: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
  React.PropTypes.oneOf([
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      content: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    }),
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      params: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }),
  ]),
),
```

Update! Found an [answer here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4553), looks like I should be using OneofType instead.

```
tabs: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
  React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      content: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    }),
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      params: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }),
  ]),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 20):

I decided to post my update to the question as an answer.

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4553). I should be using OneofType instead.

```
tabs: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
  React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      content: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    }),
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      params: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }),
  ]),
),
```